# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: node.js

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 11)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 12)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 13)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 14)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 15)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 16)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled
[0]     at C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Capstone Project\src\controllers\/subjectController.js:35:43
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0] (node:7684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 19)
```

```js
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.subjects.length; i++) {

        const subject = req.body.subjects[i];
        const { errors, isValid } = validateSubjectInput(subject);

        // Check validation
        if (!isValid) {
            return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }

        const subjectFields = {};
        for (var key in subject) {
            if (subject[key]) subjectFields[key] = subject[key].trim();
        }
        subjectFields.id = subject.id ? subject.id.trim() : '';

        console.log(subjectFields);

        // See if there is already a subject with the subject ID
        Subject.findOne({ _id: subject._id }).then(subject => {
            if (subject) {
                // Subject already exists
                Subject.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: subject._id },
                    { $set: subjectFields },
                    { new: true }
                ).then(subject => res.json(subject));
            }
            // Subject does not already exist
            else {
                new Subject(subjectFields).save().then(subject => res.json(subject));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: You are most likely sending multiple responses to a request. You are calling `res.json` inside a `for` loop. As soon as `req.body.subjects.length` is greater than `1`, the error will appear.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice at least a bit more elaborated question instead a copy-paste of your error message.

As far as I can see, express is rising an error because you are trying to return response more than once. That's why you are making a for loop and in each iteration you are sending a response.

The right approach for batch updates is to check on db for each user and to update or create, results of each operation should be stored on an array. After all users from request have been iterated over, then you return on the response the results array.

Without changing your code too much, it might looks like:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    const result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.subjects.length; i++) {
        const subject = req.body.subjects[i];
        const { errors, isValid } = validateSubjectInput(subject);
        // Check validation
        if (!isValid) {
            result.push(errors);
        } else {
            const subjectFields = {};
            for (let key in subject) {
                if (subject[key]) subjectFields[key] = subject[key].trim();
            }
            subjectFields.id = subject.id ? subject.id.trim() : '';
            console.log(subjectFields);
            // See if there is already a subject with the subject ID
            // with option {new: true} it will create an user if not exists
            Subject.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: subject._id },
                { $set: subjectFields },
                { new: true } 
            ).then(subject => result.push(subject));
        }
    }
    res.json(result);
});
```